# Can a Hunter learn and use tactics by himself?

Tags: chronicles-of-darkness-1e, tactics, hunter-the-vigil

I'm about to play a game where there are several other players, but they play other creatures like Vampires and Demons making me the only Hunter. Is it possible for me to use tactics without the help of any other hunter?

Answer (score 1):

One would assume no, based on the basic description I found on [Hunter Tactics & Teamwork](http://theonyxpath.com/teamwork-and-tactics-hunter-the-vigil/).

However there is nothing stopping you from developing "tactics" that incorporate your fellow monsters, it would require some hacking of the system however, but would lead to some cool narrative and story around your character having to adapt to being a lonely hunter with only monsters to help.

Answer (score 0):

RAW I believe nothing too severe should happen if your supernatural allies learn tactics. Tactics started because humans alone wont be enough to succeed in certain scenarios. But nobody says that your Kindred friend cant help you probably even better than any Hunter could. Only problem is gonna be if during the hunt you get injured and friend Vampire is already hungry...

But that just brings more drama so go for it.